# replace evey single/double qoutes with \' or \"

Tags: python, sql, string

I have about 6000 record, and I want to read them and `INSERT` them to new table.They contain single quotes and double quotes, And MySQL can not accept my query, because When prevent to my `'` (single quote) it has been closed and generate syntax error:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tr_en_ahmadali(id,sura,aya,aya_text) VALUES({0},{1},{2},'{3}');".format(str(index), str(j[index - 1]) ,str(aya_), str(k[single_aya - 1]))
print(sql)
```

When I print my query I get the following sql query:

```
INSERT INTO tr_en_ahmadali(id,sura,aya,aya_text) VALUES(34,2,27,'Who, having sealed it, break God's covenant, dividing what He ordained cohered; and those who spread discord in the land will suffer assuredly.');
```

**My Question Is:**
How can I replace every single and double quotes with \' or \" with python?

Comment: Using `format` or string concatenation to create a SQL query is dangerous and prone to errors. Use the power of the `execute` method: `db.execute("INSERT INTO tr_en_ahmadali(id, sura, aya, aya_text) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (index, j[index - 1], aya_, k[single_aya - 1]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple regex with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\)(["'])
```

This needs to be replaced by

```
\\\1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NPpbry/1/).

---

The whole thing in `Python`:

```
import re

string = """This ain't funny, you know.
But this escaped one (\") won't change."""

rx = re.compile(r'''(?<!\\)(["'])''')

string = rx.sub(r'\\\1', string)
print(string)
```

See [**another demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/bGwwhX).